# How to get multiple objects from SD card in Android?

Tags: android, object, load, sd-card

How do I load multiple objects in Android from SD card?

I got this:

```
    ObjectInput in;
    Dog dog = null;
    try
    {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/somelocation/save.data"));
        dog = (Dog) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but this only loads a singe object from the SD card.

I am thinking something like `ArrayList<Dog> dogs = in.readAllObjects()`, but this code will only come true in my dreams.

Code samples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`readObjects()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29) documentation:

> Reads the *next* object from the source stream.

So I recommend using a loop to read every dog:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
Dog dog;
try {
    in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/somelocation/save.data"));
    while((dog = (Dog) in.readObject()) != null)
        dogs.add(dog);
    in.close();
}
// catch the exceptions
```

I don't know if `dog` will ever be `null` of the top of my head, but it will definitely throw an exception if `in` tries to read past the end of the file.

Comment: Yes it did, no problems at all